# How to call a controller from a modal popover in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have three controllers, and i need this navigation:

| 1stVC | -> | popoverVC |  -> | 2ndVC |

The first one show a modal view using a popover segue, and then from the modal view, using a protocol, it should show the second controller.

The protocol calls the method, and then, it should call the second controller, but it doesn't!. I have tried performing segue, and calling the controller but nothing happens, in fact, it reloads the first controller instead call the second. Please help. I think that i must have errors in delegation, but i can't figure what.(poor english, i know)

One important thing, the firstViewcontroller is called from another controller that is in a tabbarcontoller.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code:

**PopoOverController:**

```
import UIKit
protocol basketDelegate {
func didSelectValue()
}
class PopoverViewController: UITableViewController {
var delegate: basketDelegate!
let options = ["Filters", "Basket"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    let rdc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
    self.delegate = rdc
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return options.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = colorWithHexString("#1C7393")
    cell.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    delegate?.didSelectValue()
}
}
```

**FirstController**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: AEAccordionTableViewController, 
UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate,basketDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   var Filters = PopoverViewController()
    Filters.delegate = self

}

// MARK: - Popup filter call
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
        let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}


func didSelectValue() {

    //Option 1--Failed!
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    let SecondViewControllerObject : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController;
    self.presentViewController(SecondViewControllerObject, animated: true, completion: nil);

    //Option 2--Failed
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondSegue", sender: self)

    //Option 3--Failed
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let SecondViewControllerObject : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController;
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SecondViewControllerObject)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //Option 4--Failed
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    FirstViewController()!.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //Option 5--Failed
    self.navigationController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

 }
}
```

**SecondController**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: AEAccordionTableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
@IBAction func dismissTap(sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior can be reached with an Action Sheet. Just in the First Controller add a new method to create a Contextual Menu with the same option to call the second controller. This method is called from a button.

Is a simple solution, without protocols or delegations.

In the first controller:

```
 @IBAction func showSheetASction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("click")
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        print(action)
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let CallSVCAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Filters", style: .Default) { (action) in
        // ...
        print(action)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(CallSVCAction)

    alertController.view.tintColor = colorWithHexString("#1C7393")

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first view controller should be a PopoverViewControllerDelegate, not a basketDelegate.

Comment: i have already test it, and it generates an error for Multiple Inheritance. By the way, why not to use the protocol delegation?